# SwiftData swap items in a list with relationships

Tags: swiftui, swift-data

I have been working on a workout app. I have a model "Workout" which holds a list of Exercises (EInfo). There can be multiple workouts stored in an app. I am currently trying to create an on move function for a list that shows the exercises in a workout. However, just using a simple swap function does not seem to work. Is there something I am missing? I cant seem to find much information about this

```swift
@Model
class Workout {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID
    var date: Date
    var name : String
    var exercises: [EInfo]
    var isFinished: Bool
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), date: Date = Date.now, name: String = "New Workout", exercises: [EInfo] = [], isFinished: Bool = false) {
        self.id = id
        self.date = date
        self.name = name
        self.exercises = exercises
        self.isFinished = isFinished
    }

}
@Model
class EInfo {
    @Attribute(.unique) var id: UUID
    var name: String
    var sets: [ESet]
    var orderIndex: Int
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String = "", sets: [ESet] = [ESet()]) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.sets = sets
        self.orderIndex = 0
    }
    func isCompleted()->Bool{
        return sets.allSatisfy { $0.done } && sets.count > 0
    }

//need help here
List{
    ForEach(workout.exercises) { exercise in
        HStack{
              ExerciseListView(workout: workout, exerciseInfo: exercise, isEditing: $isEditing)
               .frame(width: width, height: 40)
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)        
                 }.listRowBackground(Capsule().fill(Color.blue).stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2))
                 }
                 .onMove {from, to in
                    
                            }
    }
}
```

I have tried adding orderIndex in my EInfo model, however it does not work properly

Comment: You have left out the interesting code and didn’t explain why it doesn’t work,